# AWS App Runner - Error in assuming instance role

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-app-runner

When running my TF script to create an AWS App Runner service I'm getting this error:

```
InvalidRequestException: Error in assuming instance role arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/MyAppRunnerServiceRole
```

I created the role policy trust using `AppRunnerECRAccessRole` as reference, which is auto-generated by the console, but using either that or my own below I'm getting the same issue.

Here's my TF code:

```
### IAM ###

resource "aws_iam_role" "app_runner" {
  name = "MyAppRunnerServiceRole"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "build.apprunner.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "app_runner" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.app_runner.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSAppRunnerServicePolicyForECRAccess"
}

### App Runner ###

resource "aws_apprunner_service" "main" {
  service_name = "sandbox-service"

  source_configuration {
    image_repository {
      image_configuration {
        port = "5000"
      }
      image_identifier      = "${aws_ecr_repository.main.repository_url}:latest"
      image_repository_type = "ECR"
    }
  }

  instance_configuration {
    instance_role_arn = aws_iam_role.app_runner.arn
  }

}
```

---

This is the `AppRunnerECRAccessRole` which is auto-generated by the Console when creating a new App Runner service. I would assume this same configuration would work, but it isn't.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the repository a public one?

Comment: @MarkoE private ECR -> `aws_ecr_repository`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the access and instance roles were mixed up in your code. Based on the AWS documentation [1], you need to change the trust policy to be:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "tasks.apprunner.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

The permissions policy should probably remain the same, but for the sake of the completeness of the answer, it should be something along the lines:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:DescribeImages",
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can of course limit everything except the `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` to your ECR repo. The `ecr:GetAuthroziationToken` has to be set for `"Resource": "*"`.

**Update:** Correct placement of the Access role within the [source configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apprunner_service#source-configuration) section for the `"build.apprunner.amazonaws.com"` service

```
resource "aws_apprunner_service" "example" {
  source_configuration {
    authentication_configuration {
      access_role_arn = aws_iam_role.access_role.arn
    }
  }
}
```

---

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apprunner/latest/dg/security_iam_service-with-iam.html#security_iam_service-with-iam-roles-service.instance

Comment: Getting this error now: `Authentication configuration is invalid.` - Added a print of the auto-generated role from the Console.

Comment: Regarding permissions I'm really just proof-of-concepting right now.

Comment: I don't think you can use the service policy. I can add the example policy to the question.

Comment: I've figured it out and updated your question. Thanks.